# Regex matching alphanumerics with possible dash in middle only

Tags: php, regex

I have managed to get this far:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:--?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

but the above expression doesn't limit length as I need it to.  I need the pattern to only match 5-6 characters total.  So, this is how it ought to work out:

```
safety        (valid)
safet-        (invalid)
s-a-fe        (valid)
-safet        (invalid)
s7-45         (valid)
s--fs         (invalid)
```

Consecutive hyphens are invalid.  Leading and trailing hyphens are invalid.  Overall length, which includes any hyphens, should be 5-6 characters.  I've tried replacing my `+`s with ranges (`{5,6}`), but no luck.  I appreciate any help.

---

Another route I tried was:

```
^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9-]{3,4}[A-Z0-9]$i
```

which seems good and efficient, but it allows for consecutive hyphens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lookahead at the first to specify the number of characters going to be allowed.

```
^(?=.{5,6}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lG2nG9/5)

Comment: Which of these answers is most efficient?  Which requires the fewest steps to invalidate bad entries?

Comment: @David: follow the links and click on the debugger you will see.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ah, thank you.  I was unaware of that feature.

Comment: @David: however to compare the number of steps for two patterns, you must use exactly the same test string.

Comment: even more efficient `^(?=.{5,6}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]++(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]++)*+$`

Comment: Yes, @AvinashRaj, that is even more efficient in some cases.  Thank you.
    
Now, I just need to get it into the right format for mod_rewrite and .htaccess

Comment: @AvinashRaj: No using possessive quantifiers here doesn't change nothing because the pcre engine applies an "auto-possessification" optimization for cases like this `a+b` => `a++b`.

Comment: but it reduces some steps.

Comment: Can you please help out? I used your regex for `fast-cars` and it returned false. The code i used was `preg_match("/^(?=.{5,6}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/", 'fast-cars')`

Comment: Because `fast-cars` is not 5 - 6 chars long. From OP, "I need the pattern to only match 5-6 characters total."

Answer (score 1):

```
(?!^-)(?!.*?-$)(?!.*?--)^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{5,6}$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/15

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

Try this Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/hc9mDO/1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).